# Yii Bootslider setup for carousel View issue

Tags: carousel, yii-extensions

Hi I want to set carousel view for my page and used this bootslider extension from http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootslider and I am getting this error "Illegal string offset 'image'" from the line in _list.php file. How to install carousel in Yii App

baseUrl.'/images/'.$data['image']; ?>" alt="">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//view page
$rawData=array(
array('id'=>1,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-AE.jpg'),
array('id'=>2,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Bag.jpg'),
array('id'=>3,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-BankCard.jpg'),
array('id'=>4,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Bull.jpg'),
array('id'=>5,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Chip.jpg'),
array('id'=>6,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Container.jpg'),
array('id'=>7,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Dealmaker.jpg'),
array('id'=>8,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Dollar.jpg'),
array('id'=>9,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Graph.jpg'),
array('id'=>10,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Laptop.jpg'),
array('id'=>11,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Mirror.jpg'),
array('id'=>21,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-NorthKorea.jpg'),
array('id'=>22,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-Numbers.jpg'),
array('id'=>23,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-QuickShop.jpg'),
array('id'=>24,'product'=>'nokia110','image'=>'dummy-170x170-StockExchange.jpg'),
);
$listDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array('pagination'=>false));

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootSlider',
array('itemView'=>'_list',//_lsit is the php file to render
    'id'=>'Mycarouse1',//id of Carousel
    'slide'=>array(true,2000),//to slide after 2seconds
    'dataProvider'=>$listDataProvider,
    'coloumCount'=>5,//no of items to shown in slider
));?>
```

Inside _list.php

```
<style>
a #image{
    height:150px;
}
</style>

<div class="thumbnail span2">

   <img id="image" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/'.$data['image']; ?>" alt="">

</div>
```

This should work